# I want to add my entity class to available entity classes on Netbeans

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, ejb

I'm trying to create a jpa controller classes from entity classes on netbeans. To achieve this I'm following the path herein next

com.source.jpacontrollers > persistance > (at this point ) l choose jpa controller from entity class then I check available entity classes but I can't see my entity classes there 
I wonder how to add my entity class there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Can be many Reasons but there are mainly three reasons. These are

1 Database Connection Pool problem

2 you may not have a JDBC Connector

3 you may be looking wrong place.